# Windows 10 SMB shares

Tags: file-sharing, smb, network-drive, windows-10

I just installed Windows 10 and I can't connect to any of the shared drives on my QNAP station.

My network is a private network and I have enabled file and printer sharing, network discovery and file sharing for devices that use 40 or 56-bit encryption.

On the QNAP, the Microsoft networking service is enabled (as a standalone server) and it has the latest firmware update.

I have another Windows 10 PC in the network (still on an Insider preview), which does have access to the same shares.

Comment: maybe the same problem that I am experiencing with my media center. http://superuser.com/questions/954210/windows-10-cannot-access-media-center-network-shares

Answer (score 2):

1. Run Registry Editor (REGEDIT).
2. Navigate to the following registry key:
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters`
3. Name the new value as `AllowInsecureGuestAuth` and set its value data to `1`.

or:

```
c:\windows\system32> set-smbserverconfiguration -enablesmb2protocol $false
```

Comment: Hmm, I was hoping this would work for [my issue](https://superuser.com/questions/1273217/cant-create-new-smb-scans-to-windows-10-share-folders), but it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a Seagate BA-NAS and had an issue similar to this.

I couldn't access it using the path in explorer but it can find it if you map it as a network drive.

Just make sure you enter the username including the hostname/ip

e.g. 10.10.10.100\username

Once it was mapped I could access the shares with the path like normal.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve same problem (on Windows 10 Build 17134) by :

Run PowerShell as administrator and execute this commande :

```
sc.exe config mrxsmb20 start= disabled 
sc.exe config lanmanworkstation depend= bowser/mrxsmb10/nsi
```

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2696547/how-to-detect-enable-and-disable-smbv1-smbv2-and-smbv3-in-windows-and may be a good resource to include as well.