# windows 10 cannot access media center network shares

Tags: windows-10, smb, media-server

I have a [ZyXEL NSA325 Media Server](http://www.zyxel.com/be/nl/products_services/nsa325_v2.shtml?t=p) with the default [SMB network shares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block) (e.g. `\\hostname\video\`).

In windows 7, 8 and 8.1 I was able to view the content of `\\hostname\` (i.e. the root of the network shares). And I was even able to map network drives to it (e.g. `net use X: \\hostname pwd /USER:admin /PERSISTENT:YES`).

But I recently formatted my hard drive and installed [Windows 10](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/features). **Strangely enough I can't map network drives to the root (i.e. `\\hostname\`) anymore. I can however create network mappings to specific shares** (e.g. `net use X: \\hostname\video\ ...`). Well, at least somtimes, for some it works and for some it doesn't.

I don't see a clear pattern at the moment. The strange thing is that it **sometimes** works for the shares, but **not always**. But it **never works for the root**. I just installed the most recent firmware release for the media server, but the problem persists.

Has anybody else experienced this kind of behaviour since moving to windows 10 ? Is there a workaround ?

Comment: Happens to me, but with all shares, not just Media Centre.