# Fresh Installs of Windows 10 Break SMB1 Scanning to Shared Folders

Tags: windows-10, network-shares, smb, scanner

On the latest Windows 10, I cannot do SMB scans to shared folders from any of our various network scanners at multiple companies.

If you freshly install the latest Windows 10, it breaks backwards compatibility with all of our network scanners, because it does not include [smbv1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4034314/smbv1-is-not-installed-windows-10-and-windows-server-version-1709).

I've tried to [install smbv1](http://www.randyrants.com/2017/11/windows-10-turn-on-smb-v1-for-clean-installs-starting-with-1709/), but that alone doesn't resolve the issue. I'm apparently missing some steps to truly get this feature functioning again and I cannot find a thorough guide.

**Background**

I have a network scanner in an Active Directory environment where I have several users set up so that when they scan a document it goes to their own "Scanned Documents" folder which is one level subordinate to their own "Documents" folder.

To do this, I've created an regular active directory user named "scanner" and I give this user permission to scan to the folder like this:

[image]

After this, I also give the "scanner" user NTFS permissions like this:

[image]

On the scanner, when you setup a scan destination for a user, you have to indicate the "scanner" user's username and password.

I have several users set up this way and they are successfully using the network scanner to scan to their own "Scanned Documents" folder.

However, on new Windows 10 installs, with everything setup exactly the same as describe above (where it is working for several users), I can no longer achieve this set up for new hires. The scanner just gives an unhelpfully vague "Network Error: contact your administrator".

The only difference (between where this works and where it doesn't work) is the time I set it up. The ones I set up before this month work, and any new ones I set up now do not work.

I think a Windows 10 security update might be causing this.

You see, the scanner itself (I think) doesn't even know it is dealing with an Active Directory network; it just gives a username and password to the computer it is trying to write the scan to. For the users I set up prior to this month, that is good enough, but any newly created ones I think are having to jump through an additional security hoop I'm unaware of.

How can I get this to work like it does for the user I've set up this exact same way last month?

Comment: It is difficult for me to isolate the exact update because I don't do this setup every day. Before last week, I had not done this for a whole month. But, since last week, I've been unable to succeed with this set up on 3 different workstations at two different companies. The difference on these 3 users is that they have the latest (freshly installed) Windows 10 fully updated, while the other (working) user's shares were "created" on previous versions of Windows 10. The working ones seem to be grandfathered into working because the shares were "created" on an earlier version of W10.

Comment: These scanners are not officially part of the domain from an Active Directory perspective. Although that use to be fine during authentication, I thinking that maybe there is now an additional security constraint where the scanner cannot authenticate with just username and password anymore on newly create network shares. This is merely speculation, admittedly.

Comment: Ok, I have OS build 16299.64 on one that works, and also 16299.64 on one that doesn't work. The difference is, on the one that works, the share was created prior to this build. On the one that does not work, it was created during this vary build.

Comment: I found [this related article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4034314/smbv1-is-not-installed-windows-10-and-windows-server-version-1709). I tried [installing SMB v1](http://www.randyrants.com/2017/11/windows-10-turn-on-smb-v1-for-clean-installs-starting-with-1709/), but still no luck.

Comment: I have this same exact problem; did you every find a solution?

Comment: No, I didn't; I ultimately had to stop using the smb "Scan to folder" method. Instead, I'm having to use the email method. I don't like cluttering my user's email inboxes with routine document scans, but I've found no other work-around. Windows 10 updates break more sh*t than sphincters do!

Comment: We came up with a workaround just yesterday.  We put the scan folders on the server and attach their buttons to those folders, and then map drive the server folder onto their computer.  You *could* use an old windows 7 computer to do this with as well.  We determined that it was, indeed a Windows 10 problem.  Konica techs determined it was not a Konica issue.  Great explanation, by the way, for folks unfamiliar with the smb process.  I'll propose this as a workaround solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a solution for the aching Windows 10 issue, but a viable workaround.

Take a server or Windows7 computer not suffering from the Windows10 problem.  Put all your scan folders on that machine and attach the users' scan buttons on the copier to those folders.

Then map the folders to drive letters (or just use unc shortcuts) to the folders on that machine.

Voila!  Scan folders that work like the old ones, but bypass the Windows10 issues.

*[update]*

Konica admits that the problem lies with Windows 10 updates. One of their reps told me that this problem happened nearly everywhere to Windows 10 computers - it was one of the Windows 10 updates; don't know which one yet.  (For me, I had 8 PCs who are no longer able to scan, and they all broke at the same time, so, yeah, it's a W10 update relating to smb; and I also confirm version 1709).

Before this problem began, we did experience it intermittently with various computers, both Win10 AND Win7, but that was fixable by rebooting the Konica with the main power switch.  Apparently, the DNS cache in the machine would get stale and could not be updated.  A restart of the machine would clear the DNS cache.  I've asked that they add a function to the web console to allow an admin to flush the DNS cache, but you know how that can be.